# Asus N750JV laptop Smart-Pad no longer works with gestures after lid is closed / sleep mode

Tags: windows-8, sleep, touchpad

Using Windows 8.1, after closing the lid or setting my Asus N750JV laptop to sleep / hibernate, when resuming the touchpad no longer reads multitouch gestures like pinch, zoom etc. It behaves like a regular touchpad.

Switching the touchpad on and off using <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> doesn't help either. Only a full reboot fixes it.

How does one re-initialize / run the gesture driver software?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling then reinstalling the touchpad drivers?

Comment: today everything resumed normal behavior. I simply ran the Asus Smart gesture application and functionality was restored, unlike the frustrating days till now. :) Will unin/install drivers should the issue recur...